# data attribute in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Here it's my html code

```
<select class="data">
    <option value="This is my test code" data-id='123'/>
</select>
```

Now I want to access a data attribute in jquery 
here it's my jquery code

```
$( ".data" ).change(function() {
    var Id = $(this).data("id")
    alert("id:  "+Id);
});
```

but when I'm tried this one it's give a undefine value.
please help me.

Comment: `$(this).find(':selected').data("id")`

Comment: and `options` tags should not be self closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
$( ".data" ).change(function() {
    var Id =  $(this).find('option:selected').data("id")
    alert("id:  "+Id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `select` element doesn't have `data` attributes. You need to find the child `option` of `select` then you can use `.data()`

*Use*

```
var Id = $(this).find('option').data("id");
//For selected option
//var Id = $(this).find('option:selected').data("id");
```

`this` refers to element which invoked the handler, in current scenario it will be `select`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).on('change', '.data', function (){

    var id = $(this).find('[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').data('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7wxabakt/)